# python mock patch not working on function used in __attrs_post_init__

Tags: python, python-unittest

here's my mock:

```
        with mock.patch('utils.auth.get_access_token', mock.Mock(return_value=self.mock_access_token)) as mock_get_access_token:
            self.phraseController = PhraseController(
                cognito_client_id=self.cognito_client_id,
                cognito_client_secret=self.cognito_client_secret,
                raw_object_key=self.raw_object_key,
                backend_url=self.backend_url,
                cdn_url= self.cdn_url,
                tagging_version=self.tagging_version,
                output_dir= self.output_dir,
                event_time= self.event_time,
                output_bucket=self.output_bucket,
                s3_endpoint_url = self.s3_endpoint_url
            )
```

and the method that gets called after init in PhraseController:

```
from utils.auth import get_access_token

@define(auto_attribs=True)
class PhraseController():
    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.access_token = get_access_token(self.cognito_client_id, self.cognito_client_secret)
...
```

I just want to mock out get_access_token but it won't pick up the mock.

Answer (score 0):

Oh geeze - looks like I have to do:

```
        with mock.patch('main.phrase_controller.get_access_token', autospec=True) as mock_get_access_token:
```